# Alternatives to JSON-object binding in Android application

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

From my Android application I need to use a RESTful web service that returns me a list of objects in json format.
This list can be very long (about 1000/2000 object.).

What I need to do is to search and retrive just some of the objects inside the json file.

Due to the limited memory of mobile device, I was thinking that using object-binding (using for example GSON library) can be dangerous.

Which are the alternatives for solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If you are using gson, use gson streaming](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming).

I've added the sample from the link and added my comment inside of it:

```
public List<Message> readJsonStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    reader.beginArray();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        Message message = gson.fromJson(reader, Message.class);
        // TODO : write an if statement
        if(someCase) {
            messages.add(message);
            // if you want to use less memory, don't add the objects into an array. 
            // write them to the disk (i.e. use sql lite, shared preferences or a file...) and
            // and retrieve them when you need.
        }
    }
    reader.endArray();
    reader.close();
    return messages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example

1) Read the list as a stream and handle the single JSON entities on the fly and save only those that are of interest to you

2) Read the data into String object/objects and then find the JSON entities and handle them one by one instead of everything at the same time. Ways to analyse the String for JSON structures include regular expressions or manual indexOf combined with substring -type analysis.

1) is more efficient but requires a bit more work as you have to handle the stream at the same time where as 2) is probably more simple but it requires you to use quite a big Strings as temporary means.